# la funcion no me suma los numeros con puntos, omite los numeros despues del punto

Tags: javascript, html, api

Buenas estoy haciendo unos calculos en javascript, me llama el nombre de la vereda y la capacidad de usuario, todo bien hast ahi, pero al momento de hacer la suma para sacar el total no me suma los numeros que tienen punto en el array ejemplo 1.000 + 500 se vuelve 501 en vez de 1.500

```
/** Función para ver la cantidad de usuarios por vereda */
document.getElementById("btnWIFI_Por_Veredas").addEventListener("click"
    , (e) => {
        let total = 0; 
        let vereda = '';
        let mensaje = '';
       
        datosJson.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (element.vereda != vereda) {
                if (vereda != '') {
                    mensaje = mensaje + `
(${vereda}) =  ${total} \n`;
                }
                vereda = element.vereda;
                total = Number(element.capacidad_de_usuarios);
            } else {
                total = total + Number(element.capacidad_de_usuarios);
            }
        });
        console.log(mensaje);
        swal('capacidad de usuarios total segun la vereda', mensaje);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Por que la suma con `.` lo agarra como `float`. Debes modificar la función de suma y agregar la función de javascript [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) que convierte una cadena en un entero o [`Número.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) que analiza un argumento de cadena y devuelve un número entero de la raíz o base especificada. Puedes consultar los ejemplos aquí.